# Structured Data (schema.org) ItemList, Article, or both?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I am adding structured data to a new page which could sensibly be defined as either an article (http://schema.org/Article) or an Item List (http://schema.org/ItemList), as it is a news article about a new top 10, where all 10 items exist on their own pages elsewhere on our site.

So this page has a title, author, some unique content, a publish date... but it also has a ranked list of items.

Is there a best practice for use of schema.org structured data that would add weight to going with one or the other? Or could we even use both definitions on the same page to define the list within the article?

Comment: A big win for what?    Who or what are you expecting to consume this data?

Comment: Just looking for best practice. Updated the question with regard to this.

Comment: Best practice for what?   There is no point in finding some random schema to apply to your page.   You have to know who is going to use it and how they get the data.

Comment: Haven't you seen Field of Dreams? If you build it, they will come. The OP was very specific that the schema he's considering is NOT random & in fact sounded like a very good match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both, if the `ItemList` is the primary thing the `Article` is about.

Use the **[`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property** of the [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) type to provide the [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList).

`mainEntity` is typically used to denote the primary thing a `WebPage` is about (e.g., probably the `Article` in your case), but this is not the only way how it can be used (bold emphasis mine):

> Indicates the primary entity described in some page **or other `CreativeWork`**.

You could use `mainEntity` for both ways in the same document:

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ItemPage">

  <article property="mainEntity" typeof="Article">

    <ul property="mainEntity" typeof="ItemList">
    </ul>

  </article>

</body>
```

If the `ItemList` is not the primary thing the `Article` is about, there doesn’t seem to be a suitable property to link these items. The [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property can’t be used, because it expects a `CreativeWork` as value, but `ItemList` isn’t one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a JSON-LD example I am using.  Not an expert but this validates:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "ItemPage",
      "mainEntityofPage": {
          "@type": "WebPage",
          "@id": "https://yoursite.com"
      },
      "mainEntity": {
           "@type": "Article",
           "mainEntity": {
                "@type": "ItemList",
                "itemListElement":[
                    {
                        "@type": "ListItem",
                        "position": 1,
                        "item": {
                            "@id": "https://...",
                            "name": "..."
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "ListItem",
                        "position": 2,
                        "item": {
                            "@id": "https://...",
                            "name": "..."
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "ListItem",
                        "position": 3,
                        "item": {
                            "@id": "https://...",
                            "name": "..."
                        }
                    }
                ]
           }
      }
    }
    </script>
```